# Show image when clicking text

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to toggle an image open and closed when clicking a text link.

I was fortunate enough to find the code below on this site. It works wonderfully, with one exception. When the page is first loaded, or if you refresh the page, the image visibly flashes on the screen, before becoming hidden. Is there a way to modify the code below so the image is hidden prior to the page loading?

JavaScript:

```html
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.image_chart').hide();

        $('.popup').click(function() {
            $(this).next().slideToggle();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```html
<div>
    Please refer to our <a href="#" class="popup size-chart"><u>Size Chart</u></a> to find your best fit.
    <div class="image_chart">
        <img src="https://placed my image URL here.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can simply remove `$('.image_chart').hide();` from your JS code, and add `.image_chart { display: none; }` to your CSS

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

The first time, keep your image hidden by adding style and change your style by clicking.

Like this:

```html
<div class="image_chart hide">
    .hide{display : none}
    .active{display : block}
```

Now while clicking on the text, check which class is appended with that div, like this:

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.popup').click(function() {
        var img_class = $('.image_chart').attr('class');

        var getCls = img_class.split(" ");

        if(getCls[1] == 'hide') {
            $(".image_chart").removeClass('hide');
            $(".image_chart").addClass('active');
        } else {
            $(".image_chart").removeClass('active');
            $(".image_chart").addClass('hide');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It is a beautiful thing!  Thank you so much Vikas!!